# Set label title from UIViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller, uilabel, categories

I have a viewController Category and Having a UILabel in the category.
I want to set label title from anther viewController.

when I tried getting crash.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[BaseViewController setTitleLabel:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fcfe857a580'
```

How can I achieve this.

Edit :

`TitleLabel` is a label in Category, here is the code in UIViewController category

```
 UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    btn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50);
    [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Menu"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(MenuPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIBarButtonItem *leftBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:btn];

    UIButton *btn1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    btn1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 70, 44);
    [btn1 setTitle:@"Clickme!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    btn1.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];


    UILabel *titleLabel = [UILabel new];
    titleLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 44);
    titleLabel.backgroundColor =[UIColor cyanColor];

    UIBarButtonItem *barBtn2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:btn1];
    UIBarButtonItem *barTitle = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:titleLabel];
    UIBarButtonItem *flexibleItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];

    NSArray *barBtnArray = @[leftBtn,flexibleItem,barTitle,barBtn2];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = barBtnArray;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that since the label property is declared in the `.m` file. It won't be accessible outside, if you try to access, then it'll crash (It's something like private property). You have 2 option to solve this.

**Option 1**

Declare label property in `.h` file itself

**Option 2**

Write a public method which takes an `NSString` as it's argument and sets it as the value of your label.

Answer (score 0):

UIViewController doesn't have property of titleLabel. Check your category class.

Comment: Can you post some more code so we can figure out the problem.

Comment: I have  added label code from UIViewcontroller Category.

Comment: Not sure how are you adding title label into uiviewcontroller but you cant add properties and variables into category you can only add methods.

Comment: i have added on navigation controller.

Comment: ok did you import that category where you are trying to access that label?